# How to create img tags in c# code behind inside a div according to the div class?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have the following div tag :

```
<div class="slideshow"></div>
```

I would like to create several img tags inside that div in c# codebehind as follows :

```
<div class="slideshow">
     <img src="images/image1.png" alt="" width="600" height="300" />
     <img src="images/image2.png" alt="" width="600" height="300" />
     <img src="images/image3.png" alt="" width="600" height="300" />
</div>
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: @akhil I have no idea how to do this !

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET web forms or ASP.NET MVC? Do you need to create fixed number of those img or unknown dynamically calculated number? You need to specify more details

Comment: @Karamafrooz ok take a look at my asnwer It might help you a bit

Comment: @Dmitry Osinovskiy  I use ASP.NEt webforms , and number of img tags are unknown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to convert `html` tag to `Htmlserver` control and also specify the `id` attribute.

```
<div class="slideshow" runat="server" id="slideshow"></div>
```

Code-behind:

```
 slideshow.Controls.Add(new HtmlImage()
        { 
              Src="",
              Alt="",
              Width=200,
              Height=200
        });
```

Comment: thank you so much ! It solved my problem ! nice and eaasy code ;)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at 
http://learning2code.net/Learn/2009/8/12/Adding-Controls-to-an-ASPNET-form-Dynamically.aspx

Convert html tag to server control.

```
<div id="divid" runat="server"></div>
```

and in code behing you can use

```
Image img = new Image();
divid.Controls.Add(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

using For loop inside the codebehind  // this will create 10 image tag for you like you asked

```
For(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myPanel.Controls.Add( new HtmlImage()  //OR you can have ServerSide Control eg: new Image ()  
              { 
                            Src = "Image/Image" + i + ".png",
                            Alt = "my image" + i,
                            Width = 600,
                            Height = 300
              });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the `<asp:Image />` tag?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the TagBuilder class, this will assist in building what you need

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs

I'm not 100% sure this can be used with WebForms though, I have only used in MVC.